# Intel wifi 6230 slows down when cable unplugged

Tags: 12.10, wireless, 11.04, intel-wireless

I've just purchased a dell l502x with an intel 6230 wifi. 
I've installed ubuntu 11.04 64  bit. 
It works, but when i use only the battery the connection slows down (my maximum download is 800kB and when my dell is unplugged it goes down to 200kB).
I think that is a sort of power saving, but how can i manage that?

Anybody knows something about that?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```